# Sending notifications when model is updated via Nova

Tags: php, laravel-5.8, laravel-nova

I have an `Order` model that I am observing for updates. When an update occurs on the model, I am checking if a field `paymentStatus` is set to `paid` or not. If the `paymentStatus` is `paid`, I want an email notification sent to the users.

Testing on postman sends the notification as intended but when the update is done on Nova, no notification is sent even though the update is successful and `paymentStatus` is set to `paid`.

How can I get the notification sent when update is done on Nova?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps someone else. I still haven't found out the reason why update on nova doesn't trigger email notification being using model observer.

I was able to achieve this by using nova actions. In the action handle method, we can send emails after our logic.